# How to open a html with a button inside <iframe>

Tags: html, css, iframe

Right so here's the problem.
The part on the left with the dummy text is my `iframe` and on the right is my menu. The buttons inside that menu open up new html pages like usual.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Now what I would like it to do, is change the `iframe` content.
While remaining on the same html main page. But I can't really figure out how.

**Iframe**

```
<div id="vulling">                                              
     <div id="iframe">                                                    
          <iframe src="iframe/index.html" width="950px" height="590px" frameborder="0" name="iframe_a">Iframes worden niet ondersteund door deze browser.
          </iframe>
```

```
#iframe {
margin-top: 25px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 0px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

**Button**

```
<div id="menu">                                                    
  <p id="menu">                                                     
    <a href="index.html"><button class="btn">Home</button><br></a>    
    <a href="ontwerpen.html"><button class="btn">Ontwerpen</button><br></a>   
    <a href="tekeningen.html"><button class="btn">Tekeningen</button><br></a>  
    <a href="links.html"><button class="btn">Links</button><br></a>  
 </p>                                        
</div>


.btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Is it an idea to make an iframe for each "page" you want to create, then give the selected iframe  ```display: block``` and all the other iframes ```display: none```?

Comment: @Jeremy how would that look on the button, codewise

Comment: @GinoBerkers added it as an answer

Comment: @Jeremy Thnx, going to look into it after work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using something like the following. Add an `<script>` to your html page or add the function to an javascript file. You might have to edit the code a bit to make it fit in your project.

```js
var iframes = document.getElementsByClassName('iframe');
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
 
  for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', toggleContent, false);
  }

  function toggleContent(){
    var itemID = this.id;
    for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
      iframes[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    console.log(itemID);
    var activeFrame = document.getElementsByClassName(itemID);
    activeFrame[0].classList.add("active");
  }
```

```css
.content{
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  Background: blue;
}

.iframe{
  display: none; 
}

.active{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

iframe{
  background-color: white;
}

.menu{
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.btn{
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="iframe iframe1 active">
      <h1>Item 1</h1>
      <iframe src="https://example.org" width="300" height="100"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="iframe iframe2">
      <h1>Item 2</h1>
      <iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avocado" width="300" height="100"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="iframe iframe3">
      <h1>Item 3</h1>
      <iframe src="https://example.com/" width="300" height="100"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><button class="btn" id="iframe1">Item 1</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn" id="iframe2">Item 2</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn" id="iframe3">Item 3</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Added this to my suggested solution, thanks.